# Get list of rows without any references in other tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that holds translations in an entire system and other tables reference to it, for example something like this:

```
Table "translations"
id | title
----------------------------
 1 | First Translation
 2 | Second Translation
```

And second table with foreign key pointing to `translations`:

```
Table "article"
id | translation_id | ...
 1 | 1              | ...
```

I would like to get a list of rows that are not referenced by any other table (in this example row with id=2).

Number of tables might change and I would like to have a general solution that will operate on native relations mechanism in psql.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys defined _to_ the translations table? In that case this could probably be done using dynamic SQL and a PL/pgSQL function

Comment: What do you mean "Number of tables might change"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, reference is to translations table, as described :)

Comment: I suspect that any solution to this will be ugly.  You want to have a look at `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/11/sql-outer-joins.html).  The good news is that you could write a query that includes all of the tables that make up the outer join and I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name that a stored procedure or function could be created to handle this dynamically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean there might be a different table named "foo" also with the reference to "translations". I want to have a generic solution that is based on references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the function you need. Bellow is the sample data I created to test it. In my data sample the return should be the `ID 4` from the table `t1`. To your case the `t1` table would be the `translations` table.

You have to change it to your tables. It shouldn't be difficult.

```
create table t1 (
    id integer primary key not null,
    lang varchar(10)
);

create table t2 (
    id integer primary key not null,
    id_t1 integer,
     constraint fk_t2 foreign key (id_t1) references t1(id)
);

create table t3 (
    id integer primary key not null,
    id_t1 integer,
    constraint fk_t3 foreign key (id_t1) references t1(id)
);

insert into t1 values (1, 'pt'), (2, 'us'), (3,'cn'), (4,'uk');
insert into t2 values (1, 1), (2,2);
insert into t3 values (1, 1), (2,3);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listAllReferences()
  RETURNS setof integer AS
$$
declare
   fullSQL text;
   rs RECORD;
begin
   fullSQL := '';
   for rs in 
        SELECT 'select t1.id from t1 inner join ' || tc.table_name || ' ON ('||tc.table_name||'.'||kcu.column_name||' = t1.id)' as sel
          FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
                 JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
                   ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
                 JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
                   ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
         WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
           AND ccu.table_name='t1' loop
      if fullSQL != '' then
         fullSQL := fullSQL || ' union ';
      end if;
      fullSQL := fullSQL || rs.sel;
   end loop;
   return query
      execute 'select t1.id 
                 from t1 left join ('||fullSQL||') alltb on (t1.id = alltb.id)
                where alltb.id is null';
   return;

end;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And to use it just do:

```
select * from listAllReferences();
```

It will return:

```
listallreferences
       4
```

Future tables with reference to your language table will also get covered because I'm getting the data from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` of PostgreSQL

Also you may have to add another filter () to the query on the implicit cursor which is `AND tc.table_schema = 'yourSchemaName'`